# flowtype function overloading error: `Could not decide which case to select.`

Tags: javascript, flowtype

**TS - passed**

`[{name: 1}]` is matched with `{ value: T }[]` and `T[]` the first signature is chosen, correct type is returned `T[]`;

```
// TS example
function transformDataToForm<T>(data: { value: T }[]): T[];
function transformDataToForm<T>(data: T[]): T[];
function transformDataToForm<U, T extends { value?: U }>(data: T[]): (T | U)[] {
    return data.map(item => item.value ? item.value : item);
}

const res1: {name: number}[] = transformDataToForm([{name: 1}]);
const res2: number[] = transformDataToForm([{value: 1}]);
```

**Flow - error**

I think for flow should exist only one signature to match.

```
declare function transformDataToForm<T>(data: { value: T }[]): T[];
declare function transformDataToForm<T>(data: T[]): T[];
function transformDataToForm<U, T: { value?: U }>(data: T[]): (T | U)[] {
    return data.map(item => item.value ? item.value : item);
}        

const res1: {name: number}[] = transformDataToForm([{name: 1}]);
//                             ^ Could not decide which case to select. Since case 1 [1] may work but if it doesn't case 2 [2] looks promising too. To fix add a type annotation to inferred union of array element types (alternatively, provide an annotation to summarize the array element type) [3]      

// const res2: number[] = transformDataToForm([{value: 1}]);
```

[Try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwxilQGdEcYBbAESgygBUcAxCygHgYD4AKYOqAC54Ab3gA3KBGQhhDeAF8A2gF0AlHNUBuAFChIsBCnTY8BIqXJVa9Jqyqde-epvWvdxzLnyFiZNjaMLGzsAKoANPAMwmKS0iAA-MKhik4CrhrwPPIAPvChaqqiOvCl8HAYyDD4zlAAdJRQAA48WBgglPAAvFzwbR11cTLwCX3tlINSw8L9lGq6CmVL8Do6YHgkGOUgJACMMahQlLLwqMiUAEYgMMoq3eZ+VjQCdmw8SiKHx8K7Cuq6AHoAcsQaCwWUAHrwADCOGQEGApxwW30WFA8AA7gALLBgLHwMBQEgIDA4eDEiDgDB1eAAZSw6AQhOJ8F28CUuzujQAnpiKABreAXZBbLCIMbwYA4HaoADkW2ZCAATOylXcIDgcPySPAmjAcJQsCQGQBzAiamlMJBYAAe8CgwERUAI3KaCGIqGRdG85r6qEQ1zgiLQPpw4tgRF5IEpx1QWwwrp2WSk7Wq3vE0e5kT1OHEaPd+A9XtMPjJJHOjRgWAAXiSse6YJH4NGOiA4y63Wp2QBmO7LErgwdD-tAgkbLZwEhK4RnS7XIpdB6WAIvYJUd4iIYnX7-Yd7oc6IA)

What is the correct way to use function overloading in Flow?

What are the correct types for `transformDataToForm`?

Comment: 3 years and no answer?